# Personal One Drive on Domain User Account

Tags: windows, dns, onedrive

**TLDR: Want to access personal OneDrive from Domain account. Cannot even access OneDrive. Was able to do it before Windows 10 Pro clean install.**

I am trying to access my personal Onedrive while signed into my Domain profile. I was able to do this perfectly fine at one point, but after a clean install of windows 10 pro, I can no longer even access Onedrive. On the local account and the "administrator@(domain)" account, I can access my OneDrive perfectly fine.

I contacted Microsoft about this, they are stumped up until the point of "Oh, it's a domain issue. We can't help you from here." I have admin rights but cannot install Onedrive on my domain account. I learned you can't uninstall it either. At one point I tried dragging and dropping the OneDrive folder from the local account to the domain account. It gave me access to it as a library, but not any of the functionality of OneDrive in earnest. I would have to sign off and log onto the local account to resync files, I believe.

Seeing how another account on the domain can access my one drive personally on this PC, I doubt it is a domain issue. As a work around, I was able to download a OneDrive app, which worked but I want access to the files while in my directories, not through an app.

Comment: Have tried reinstalling windows multiple times. Tried uninstalling OneDrive completely to install on the Domain Account, failed. Need to try creating a new user and accessing my OneDrive from that, to see if it's my profile specifically.